# How to create anonymous block in DB2 call via GUI tool like DbVisualizer

Tags: oracle, plsql, db2

Code :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare count_t integer  : = 0;
   BEGIN
       CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Hello' );
       CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'count_t-' || count_t );
   END;
```

Unable to execute in DB2.
Error :

```
[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "SERVEROUTPUT" was found following "SET ".  Expected tokens may include:  "SSA".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11
```

And also

```
[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "declare count_t integer" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<select>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11
```

Comment: Please, learn how to format your code / messages here properly to make them look easily readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use different Statement Delimiter / Terminator to run compound statements.
Every client tool has its own methods of setting it.
Dbvisualizer:

```
Tools\Tool Properties\SQL Commander\Statement Delimiters:
SQL Statement Delimiter:  
  SQL Statement Delimiter 1: @  
  SQL Statement Delimiter 2: @
```

[Using the DBMS Output Tab](https://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG130/Using+the+DBMS+Output+Tab):

> **Only in DbVisualizer DbVisualizer Pro edition.**
> This feature is only available in the DbVisualizer Pro edition.

```
BEGIN
  declare count_t integer default 0;      
  CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Hello' );
  CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'count_t-' || count_t );
END
@
```